# Is there an way to make loading progress bar run again in visjs?

Tags: vis.js

I have created a new network visualization using visjs and I follow the example here: http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/loadingBar.html to implement a loading progress bar and it worked perfectly.
I can switch to other 2 visualizations using a radio button. When I load the other visualizations the loading bar doesn't appear again. 
I would like to know how to call the loading bar again.
Thanks in advance.

```html
...
<input type="radio" name="op" onclick="net1()" checked>
<input type="radio" name="op" onclick="net2()">

<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="network1"></div>
   <div id="network2" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div id="loadingBar">
     <div class="outerBorder" style="left: 100%;">
        <div id="text">0%</div>
        <div id="border">
           <div id="bar"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   function function1(){
...//create network
    network.on("stabilizationProgress", function (params) {
       var maxWidth = 496;
       var minWidth = 20;
       var widthFactor = params.iterations / params.total;
       var width = Math.max(minWidth, maxWidth * widthFactor);
       document.getElementById('bar').style.width = width + 'px';
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Math.round(widthFactor * 100) + '%';
    });
    network.once("stabilizationIterationsDone", function () {
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '100%';
       document.getElementById('bar').style.width = '496px';
       document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 0;
       setTimeout(function () {
          document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.display = 'none';
       }, 500);
    });
   }

   function function2(){
...//create onther network
    network.on("stabilizationProgress", function (params) {
       var maxWidth = 496;
       var minWidth = 20;
       var widthFactor = params.iterations / params.total;
       var width = Math.max(minWidth, maxWidth * widthFactor);
       document.getElementById('bar').style.width = width + 'px';
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Math.round(widthFactor * 100) + '%';
    });
    network.once("stabilizationIterationsDone", function () {
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '100%';
       document.getElementById('bar').style.width = '496px';
       document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 0;
       setTimeout(function () {
          document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.display = 'none';
       }, 500);
    });
   }
</script>

<script>
   function net1() {
      function1();
      document.getElementById('network1').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('network2').style.display = "none";
    }
    function net2() {
      document.getElementById('network1').style.display = "none";
      function2();
      document.getElementById('network2').style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it changing the methods `stabilizationProgress` and `stabilizationIterationsDone` to:

```
network.on("stabilizationProgress", function (params) {
    document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 1;
    var maxWidth = 496;
    var minWidth = 20;
    var widthFactor = params.iterations / params.total;
    var width = Math.max(minWidth, maxWidth * widthFactor);
    document.getElementById('bar').style.width = width + 'px';
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = Math.round(widthFactor * 100) + '%';
});
network.on("stabilizationIterationsDone", function () {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '100%';
    document.getElementById('bar').style.width = '496px';
    document.getElementById('loadingBar').style.opacity = 0;
});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution! If this answers your question, please mark the answer accepted